# Crash when formatting (Dart sdk: '>=2.0.0-dev.65.0 <2.0.0')

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I updated the Dart SDK installed on my computer to the version `sdk: '>=2.0.0-dev.65.0 <2.0.0'`. When I launch webdev serve, I receive this error message:

```
Crash when formatting: [AsciiControlCharacter] The control character U+001A can only be used in strings and comments.
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in range 0..271155, inclusive: 272138
#0  _StringBase.[] [...]
```

Is it happening to you too? How can I solve?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rerun `pub global activate webdev` and try again.

Comment: I did it and I deleted .dart-tool folder. Then I rerun `webdev serve`, and ... it worked! Thank you very much!